# Open API 3 and Flask app response validation problem with oneOf

Tags: python-3.x, validation, flask, swagger, openapi

I have a simple Flask app with Open API 3. I've defined the yml file in this way, using oneOf for different 200 responses

```
paths:
  /document:
    post:
      operationId: document.classify
      tags:
        - document
      summary: Classify a document and return the belonging cluster
      description: Assign a class to the input document
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              ...
        description: Document to classify
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                oneOf:
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Output'
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Fault'
components:
  schemas:
    Output:
      type: object
      properties:
        dID:
          type: string
        ClassificationConcepts:
          type: array
          items:
            properties:
              Concept:
                type: array
                description: Comma separated classification tags
                items:
                  type: string
    Fault:
      type: object
      properties:
        faultCode:
          type: string
          description: Fault code number
        faultMessage:
          type: string
          description: Fault code message
```

But the validation step doesn't pass the output, with error "Failed validating 'oneOf' in schema" On instance: {'ClassificationConcepts': [{'Concept': ['Test']}], 'dID': 'test'}.

```
'oneOf': [{
    'properties': {
      'ClassificationConcepts': {
        'items': {
          'properties': {
            'Concept': {
              'description': 'Comma '
              'separated '
              'classification '
              'tags',
              'items': {
                'type': 'string'
              },
              'type': 'array'
            }
          }
        },
        'type': 'array'
      },
      'dID': {
        'type': 'string'
      }
    },
    'type': 'object',
    'x-scope': ['']
  }
  ...
]
}
```

Here my Python code:

```
dID = body.get("dID")
    try:
        class_predicted = classifier.classification_doc(document_text)
        result = {"dID": dID,
                "ClassificationConcepts": [
                    {"Concept": class_predicted}
                ]
                }
        response = jsonify(result)
        response.headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        return response

    except ValueError as e:
        result = {"faultCode": 1, "faultMessage": e.__cause__ }
        return make_response(
            jsonify(result)
        )
```

Comment: Why do you return `Fault` as 200 instead of the appropriate 4xx error code (e.g. 400 Bad Request)?

Comment: True, thanks for the bug fix!